# jquery datatable fnUpdate or fnDraw?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the 6th column is a button (enable or disable depends on the second column), when I press an 
enable button both the 2nd and the 6th column should change, here is what I did :

```
<tbody>
        <logic:iterate id="mdataenv" name="metadataEnvList">
            <tr  id='<bean:write name="mdataenv" property="interfaceEnvironment"/>'>
                <td><bean:write name="mdataenv" property="interfaceEnvironment"/></td>
                <td><bean:write name="mdataenv" property="disabled"/></td> 
                <td><bean:write name="mdataenv" property="creatorName"/></td>                 
                 <td class="center"><ichtml:dtfmt vDate="${mdataenv.createdAt}"/></td>
                <td><bean:write name="mdataenv" property="updaterName"/></td>
                 <td class="center"><ichtml:dtfmt vDate="${mdataenv.updatedAt}"/></td>

                  <logic:equal value="T" name="mdataenv" property="disabled" >
                     <td class="center">
                        <html:link href="JavaScript:void()"  styleClass="button enable" style="margin:10px;margin-right:30px;">Enable</html:link>
                     </td>
                  </logic:equal>
                 <logic:notEqual value="T" name="mdataenv"  property="disabled" >
                     <td class="center">
                        <html:link href="JavaScript:void()"  styleClass="button delete" style="margin:10px;margin-right:30px;">Disable</html:link>
                     </td> 
                 </logic:notEqual>

            </tr>
        </logic:iterate> 
   </tbody>
```

The JS code :

```
 $('#saiMdataEnvListTable .enable').on('click', function() {  
    var ans = confirm("Do you want to enable this Environment?");
    if(ans==true){
        var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        alert(nRow.id);
          var target_row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0); 
           var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(target_row); 
            alert(aPos);
            oTable.fnUpdate('F',aPos,1);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<td class="center"><html:link href="JavaScript:void()"  styleClass="button delete" style="margin:10px;margin-right:30px;">Disable</html:link></td> ',aPos,6);
            alert("After fnUpdate .........");

        $.ajax({
            url: "enableEnv.do",
            data: "env=" + nRow.id + "&flagt=" + "F",
            success: function(response) {
               toastr.success(response.message);  
            }
        })
        // oTable.fnDraw();

    }
});
```

everything work fine, but button in the 6th column was not rendered with the classes button and delete, here is a pic :
http://s7.postimg.org/pmct9yah7/disable.png

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<html:link>`](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#link) is a server-side tag. It will get translated to a different html element, in this case `<a>`, before being sent to the client.

Since you are creating the element client-side, you need to use the `<a>` tag instead. Also, `styleClass` gets rendered as `class`:

```
oTable.fnUpdate('<td class="center"><a href="JavaScript:void()" class="button delete" style="margin:10px;margin-right:30px;">Disable</a></td> ',aPos,6);
```